# How many cows are required to obtain the parchment of a typical Sefer Torah?

Tags: sefer-torah, safrus, statistics, klaf-parchment

How many cows are required to obtain the parchment of a typical Sefer Torah?

I have tried estimating the question with some online sources:

- [Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/339590/jewish/How-Is-the-Torah-Made.htm) states that a Sefer Torah has 62 and 84 sheets of parchment
- The [Mishneh Torah](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.9.1?lang=bi) describes the upper-bound on dimensions but I have no idea how this translates to cow hides after being stretched and prepared in to parchment

Comment: It’s about one animal per sheet for full size sheets

Comment: https://nypost.com/2014/06/01/inside-look-at-the-making-of-a-torah/ - here it says 65

Comment: Note any kosher land animal is fine. In the times of the gemara they'd have been more likely to use deer or sheep than cows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would depend on the size of the Sefer Torah. Technically a Sefer Torah can be pocket size. I was told by those who work in the industry that the typical standard size Sefer Torah needs 60 to 65 cows for the parchment.

Comment: It's hotly debated if a Torah can (lechatchila) be pocket size. Depends if you view the margin requirements as fixed numbers or proportions.